# FPDF works locally but not online

Tags: fpdf

I have a FPDF output which works perfectly locally but there is problem online.

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at /home/wa/public_html/razpis/baza.inc.php:1)' in /home/wa/public_html/razpis/fpdf.php:271 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/wa/public_html/razpis/fpdf.php(1052): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') 
#1 /home/wa/public_html/razpis/fpdf.php(1012): FPDF->_checkoutput() 
#2 /home/wa/public_html/razpis/naredipdf.php(169): FPDF->Output('razpis.pdf', 'D') 
#3 /home/wa/public_html/razpis/razpis5.php(136): require('/home/wa...') 
#4 /home/wa/public_html/razpis/index.php(165): include_once('/home/wa...') 
#5 {main} thrown in /home/wa/public_html/razpis/fpdf.php on line 271
```

Comment: try `ini_set("display_errors", "off")` in your script at the first line

Comment: It just hides the error, the PDF is still not generated :(

Comment: Your problem is, that somewhere in advance, there is already an output, so fpdf is not able to send the `content-type` header. Try to find out where there is an output before you call `fpdf->output`

Comment: I can not fint anything... Can it be that on the main domain there is a website in wordpress not done by me. My site is located in public_html/razpis .. Can the wordpress impact the FPDF? 

on my localhost it works great, If i upload it, it just stops ..

Comment: Absolutely. FPDF _requires_ that __nothing has been output__ yet, not even a single space character. If the target website wraps your call in an output such as an html-frame, it won't work. This means, you even have to make sure that your script starts with `<?php` __immediately__ (no space or line break before)! And this is not a picky behaviour of FPDF, but is necessary for changing the http-header.

Comment: I deleted the Wordpress site from the FTP so that only mine was up, and the error was the same.

I just don't usterstand, that if it works on my local wamp, why does it not work in FTP. Can it be something with some settings?

Comment: Comment out the fpdf->output(); in your script and run it. What you see is the culprit.

Comment: I commented out, There was only a few undefined index notices, I even fixed that one, but the error is still the same.

Comment: so now there is _nothing_ on the screen anymore?

Comment: no. If I comment out the output the whole div is empty. The site strucure is index.php and then I include sites like oddano.php in like seen in the screenshot. So can the error be in the index.php?
Screenshot: http://shrani.si/f/T/XJ/4S7kLCC4/123.png

Comment: Probably. What if you run your script directly, does it work?

Comment: It's the same error if i only run the naredipdf.php file directly.

I this the problem is in bazaa.inc.php because i include this like include_once 'bazaa.inc.php';

The bazaa.inc.php is a simple connection to database:
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "prof", "pass", "raz");